Finding the heat absorbed/emitted by 2 moles of C2H6 according to the dehydrogenation of ethane
I'm trying to solve an exam question for my general chemistry class which goes like this:

Find the heat absorbed/emitted by 2 moles of $\ce{C2H6}$ according to the following reaction:
$$\ce{C2H6 (g) -> C2H4 (g) + H2 (g)}$$

I'm given the following data:
\begin{align}
\Delta H_f^\circ(\ce{CO2},g) &= \pu{-393.5 kJ/mol}\\
\Delta H_f^\circ(\ce{H2O},g) &= \pu{-241.8 kJ/mol}\\
\Delta H_\mathrm{comb.}^\circ(\ce{C2H6}) &= \pu{-1427.7 kJ/mol}\\
\Delta H_\mathrm{comb.}^\circ(\ce{C2H4}) &= \pu{-1322.9 kJ/mol}
\end{align}
I figured out I have to find $\Delta H_\mathrm{reaction}^\circ$.
The first thing that came to mind was to use Hess's law so I wrote down the combustion reactions for both $\ce{C2H6}$ and $\ce{C2H4}$ but from this point I have literally no idea what to do.
Also supposing that I manage to find $\Delta H_\mathrm{reaction}^\circ$. How do I find the heat for 2 moles? Do I have to multiply $\Delta H_\mathrm{reaction}^0 \times \pu{2 mol} \ \ce{C2H6}$? Or is there another way?


The first thing that came to mind was to use Hess's law so I wrote down the combustion reactions for both $\ce{C2H6}$ and $\ce{C2H4}$ but from this point I have literally no idea what to do.

Here are the two combustion reactions:
$$\ce{C2H6 + 7/2 O2 -> 2CO2 + 3H2O}$$
$$\ce{C2H4 + 3 O2 -> 2CO2 + 2H2O}$$
You want to use Hess's law to combine reactions with known enthalpy of reaction to get to the reaction of interest. Let's try to add the first to the reverse of the second:
$$\ce{C2H6 + 7/2 O2 + 2CO2 + 2H2O -> 2CO2 + 3H2O + C2H4 + 3 O2}$$
The carbon dioxide cancels out, and we can also substract two waters and three dioxygen units from both sides:
$$\ce{C2H6 + 1/2 O2 -> H2O + C2H4}$$
This is almost the reaction we want. To get rid of the water and the dioxygen, and to get some dihydrogen, we can add this reaction:
$$\ce{H2O -> H2 + 1/2 O2}$$
and we get
$$\ce{C2H6 + 1/2 O2 + H2O -> H2O + C2H4 + H2 + 1/2 O2}$$
Now you have to do sum up the reaction enthalpies of all these reactions appropriately to get the reaction enthalpy of the given reaction.

Also supposing that I manage to find $\Delta H_\mathrm{reaction}^\circ$. How do I find the heat for 2 moles? Do I have to multiply $\Delta H_\mathrm{reaction}^0 \times \pu{2 mol} \ \ce{C2H6}$? Or is there another way?

That is how you do it.
